# Facebook Page SDK - Remote Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

What I am trying to do is have a remote script post updates to my companies FB page a few times a day.  This script would be ran on a server, and would not be accessing FB site directly.

After reading through the FB Developers Graph API documentation, and a bunch of stuff online, it appears that this is not possible.  From what I have gathered, you would first need a user access token, and from that you can eventually get to a page access token which would allow you to update/post-to a page.

The problem is that it appears the only way you can get a user access token is through a site that allows users to 'Log In via FB', and therefore be able to access this token as its returned from a FB redirect page.

I could not find any documentation about being about to remotely sign in through a rogue script in order to get an access token.  If I'm missing something, would someone be able to possibly direct me to documentation about how to do this, if possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No you are correct. But if you extend the page access token it is valid forever. So just login once and then store the page access token

Comment: OK.  That's kind of what it seemed to me.  Wish they had a better way of doing it.  Thanks!

Comment: That is the best way to do it. Otherwise random apps would ask users for their username and password and which they then could use to do anything to their account